# discord bot if statment only if veriable equals yes, the bot sends embed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Here is the relevant code:

```
var Started = "no";

// other stuff

// HERE IS WHERE THE CODE IS
client.on('ready', () => {
    var channel = client.channels.find(channel => channel.id === '740342329973538858');
    console.log("we in bois");
    setInterval(() => {
        channel.send({
            embed: {
                meesage
            }
        });
    }, 10000);
});


// other stuff

if (msg.content === "start") {
    var Started = 'yes';
    console.log = 'no';
}
    
// another one of the above for no
```

I cant figure out how to make an if statement to always check whether or not started is yes or no. I need to start when it is yes and stop when it is no (the code I'm talking about is the `HERE IS WHERE THE CODE IS`)

Comment: I haven't done much with discord in particular but I imagine there is some sort of event listener that your logic should be in.

Comment: yea but i don't know how to stop it from sending the embed after i send the stop message.

Comment: The setInterval will keep running. One solution is to place an `if (Started === "yes")` before `channel.send`. Also, you should only declare `var Started` once at the top of your code. Additional references should not include `var`.

Comment: Another, and more preferred, solution is to assign the `setInterval` result to a variable, and call `clearInterval(varname)` to remove it from the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `setInterval` will keep running on the defined interval, in your case every 10 seconds. One solution is to place an `if (Started === "yes")` before `channel.send`. Another, and more preferred, solution is to assign the setInterval result to a variable, and call `clearInterval(varname)` to remove it from the DOM.

As a side note - you should only declare `var Started` once at the top of your code. Additional references should not include var.

Answer (score 0):

The setInterval will keep running. One solution is to place an if (Started === "yes") before channel.send. Also, you should only declare var Started once at the top of your code. Additional references should not include var. – h0r53 9 mins ago

Comment: I posted my comments as an answer since it turned out to be the solution. That way you don't need to quote me here. If you don't mind, will you mark the question as answered?